# Accumulating Rows In A Two Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create the following output:

```
TOTAL SALES BY REGION

Region 1: 7,845.00

Region 2: 5,636.00

Region 3: 7,879.00

Region 4: 9,174.00
```

From this Array:

```
double[][] sales = {{1540.0, 2010.0, 2450.0, 1845.0},       // Region 1 sales
                    {1130.0, 1168.0, 1847.0, 1491.0},       // Region 2 sales
                    {1580.0, 2305.0, 2710.0, 1284.0},       // Region 3 sales
                    {1105.0, 4102.0, 2391.0, 1576.0}};      // Region 4 sales
```

This is what I have so far, but it prints all the numbers from the array plus the accumulation, how do i only print the sums of each row? Also, it must be done in a normal nested for loop.

```
public void print(double [][] salesArray) 
{
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < salesArray.length; i++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < salesArray[0].length; j++) {
            sum += salesArray[i][j];
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move the System.out to the outer loop?

Comment: add `sum=0;` after your inner for loop but before the outer one ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void print(double [][] salesArray) 
{
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < salesArray.length; i++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < salesArray[0].length; j++) {
            sum += salesArray[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

The difference is that you're moving the printing out to the outer loop. This way, the inner loop will do the sums of a row and then when the sum is complete, the outer loop will print it.